# Applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to a specific example

Tags: calculus

Consider the function

$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-y)} \eta(y) dy $

What happens when taking the derivative with respect to x, i.e.

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = $ ?

My logic:

By the FTC

$\frac{d}{db} \int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt = g(b)$

one should get that

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \eta(x)$

My source (in a paper) claims that

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = -f(x) + \eta(x)$

which would imply that before using the FTC, first they took derivative of the integrand resulting in the minus sign.

Can someone clarify the situation?

Thanks!

Comment: The integrand also depends on $x$, so the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't directly apply. You could first pull $e^{-x}$ outside the integral.

Answer (score 5):

Note
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-y)}\eta(y)dy=e^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^x e^y\eta(y)dy$$
Then, apply the product rule:
$$\begin{align} f'(x)&=-e^{-x}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^x e^y\eta(y)dy+e^{-x}\cdot e^x\eta(x)\\ &=-f(x)+\eta(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: d'uhh!  Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

The formula $\frac {d} {db} \int_a^{b}g(t)dt=g(b)$ is not valid when $g$ depends on $b$. Here $f(x)=e^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{y}\eta(y)dy$. Apply product rule to differentiate this. You get $f'(x)=-e^{-x} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{y}\eta(y)dy+e^{-x} e^{x}\eta (x)=-f(x)+\eta(x)$.

Comment: d'uhh!  Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=e^{-x}\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{x}}e^y\eta (y)dy.$

$f'(x)= -f(x) +e^{-x}e^{x}\eta (x)$.

Used: Product rule, and $(e^{-x})'=-e^{-x}$.